# Mondrian find dimension from facts

Tags: mdx

I need to find the actual column values of my dimensions for which facts are present.
Is there a syntax in Mondrain to find the same.
Currently I am running the below sql inner join query to find the dimension data

```
    select 
            distinct the_month as Month,
            the_year as Year,
            quarter as Quarter,
            storename as name
            storedimension,
            perioddimension,
            storevisitfact where
            storevisitfact.time_id=perioddimension.time_id
            and storevisitfact.storedimension_id=storedimensionstoredimension_id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Non Empty** will do your work:

```
select 
non empty {[Date].[Calendar].[Year].Members, [Date].[Calendar].[Quarter].Members, [Date].[Calendar].[Month].Members} * [Store].[Store].[Store].Members * [Measures].[Visits] on 0
from
[YourCube]
```